# How to capture different values for the items belong to the same group

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table to display Addon items from database.

The user must check the checkbox for the first two items namely: `gps` and `babyseat`.

So the `deposit` and `priceperday` are captured inside `add_item[]` of the checkbox.

But the third item which is Driver, there's no deposit or priceperday but price per hour.

So I gave out two radio buttons namely: **one for per8thhour rate** and the **other one for per16thhour rate**.

The problem is it captures both rate but I only want either one value of the radio button to be recorded.

Here's the table:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin-top: 20px;">
    <tr>
        <th>AddOns</th>
        <th>Deposit</th>
        <th>PricePerDay</th>
        <th>Price per 8th Hour</th>
        <th>Price per 16th Hour</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($row_addon=mysql_fetch_array($result_addon))
    {
        $add_on_id=$row_addon['addOns_id'];
        $add_on=$row_addon['addOns'];
        $deposit=$row_addon['Deposit'];
        $ppd=$row_addon['PricePerDay'];
        $pp8=$row_addon['PricePer8thHour'];
        $pp16=$row_addon['PricePer16thHour'];
        $status=$row_addon['status'];
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="add_name" value=""><?php echo $add_on;?></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="add_on"><?php echo $deposit;?></td>
        <?php 
        if(isset($add_on)&&($add_on!=='Driver'))
        {
        ?>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="add_on"><?php echo $ppd;?></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="add_on"><?php echo $pp8;?></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="add_on"><?php echo $pp16;?></td>

        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="add_on"><?php echo $ppd;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="add_on"><?php echo $pp8;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="add_on"><?php echo $pp16;?></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="add_item[]" value="<?php echo $add_on_id;?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="submit_add">
    <tr><td colspan="6"></td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm recording the value like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_add']))
{
    $add_item=$_POST['add_item'];
    echo $add_item_1=implode(',',$add_item);
}
```

How do I make it possible to catch only the value selected by user for the item driver.

At the same time group them all under one name which is addon so that I can store them as one group in session later?

FULL FORM:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
                   <?php
                   //display pickup location
                   mysql_select_db($database_bumi_conn, $bumi_conn);

                   $q="SELECT * FROM tbl_pickup_location WHERE pickup_id='$location'";

                   $r=mysql_query($q);
                   $row_show=  mysql_fetch_array($r);

                   ?>
                      <input type="hidden" name="lo" value="<?php echo $location_name=$row_show['pickup_location'];?>">
                   <?php
                   echo 'Pickup Location :'.$location_name=$row_show['pickup_location'].'<br/>';

                   //display dropoff location
                   mysql_select_db($database_bumi_conn, $bumi_conn);

                   $q_1="SELECT * FROM tbl_dropoff WHERE dropoff_id='$d_location'";

                   $r_1=mysql_query($q_1);
                   $row_show_1=  mysql_fetch_array($r_1);

                  ?>
                  <input type="hidden" name="d_lo" value="<?php echo $location_name_1=$row_show_1['dropoff_location'];?>">
                  <?php
                   echo 'Return Location : '.$location_name_1=$row_show_1['dropoff_location'].'<br/>';
                   ?>
                      <input type="hidden" name="val_1" value="<?php echo $date_value; ?>"/>
                   <?php
                   echo 'Pickup date : '.$date_value.'<br/>';
                   ?>
                       <input type="hidden" name="val_2" value="<?php echo $date_value_2; ?>"/>
                    <?php
                   echo 'Return date : '.$date_value_2.'<br/>';
                   //$days=0;

                   $days=$diff->format("%a Days");
                   echo 'Total Rental for : '.$days.'<br/>';

                   //echo"hdssssssssssssfviodrhfvuhgudfhghdfhijswdjiahsdhsndjfhzsnhio";
                   $total_days=(int)$days;

                   ?>
                       <input type="hidden" name="t_days" value="<?php echo $total_days; ?>"/>
                   <?php


                   include'calculation.php';
                   ?>
                       <input type="hidden" name="sum" value="<?php echo $sum;?>">
                       <?php


                   mysql_select_db($database_bumi_conn, $bumi_conn);
                   $q_addon="SELECT * FROM tbl_addons";
                   $result_addon=  mysql_query($q_addon)or die(mysql_error());


                       echo "<hr width=540>";
                   ?>
                   <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin-top: 20px;">
                      <tr><th>AddOns</th><th>Deposit</th><th>PricePerDay</th><th>Price per 8th Hour</th><th>Price per 16th Hour</th><th></th></tr>

                  <?php
                   while($row_addon=mysql_fetch_array($result_addon))
                   {
                       $add_on_id=$row_addon['addOns_id'];
                       $add_on=$row_addon['addOns'];
                       $deposit=$row_addon['Deposit'];
                       $ppd=$row_addon['PricePerDay'];
                       $pp8=$row_addon['PricePer8thHour'];
                        $pp16=$row_addon['PricePer16thHour'];
                       $status=$row_addon['status'];

                   ?>

                       <tr>
                           <td><input type="hidden" name="add_name" value=""><?php echo $add_on;?></td>
                           <td><input type="hidden" name="add_item[]"><?php echo $deposit;?></td>


                           <td><input type="hidden" name="add_item[]"><?php echo $ppd;?></td>

                           <td><input type="radio" name="add_item[]" value="eight"><?php echo $pp8;?></td>
                           <td><input type="radio" name="add_item[]" value="six"><?php echo $pp16;?></td>

                           <td><input type="checkbox" name="add_item[]" value="<?php echo $add_on_id;?>"/></td>

                       </tr>
                     <?php
                   }
                   ?>
                          <input type="hidden" name="submit_add">
                      <tr><td colspan="6"></td></tr>

                  </table>
                   <input type="image" src="submit.png" name="submit" value="submit"  onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to proceed to checkout?');"href="checkout.php" style="padding-left:20px;" title="Add to cart"/>




                     </form>
```

Comment: I think your html structure is not complete here. Please provide the full form. I could only see one $add_item field item here...

Comment: @BlankHead I added the full form...Please check..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To select one `radio` button at once, you have to give the all `radio` button's name same. 
Otherwise you have to use `javascript/jquery` to deselect others when one is selected.

if you give all radio button name same, then when you post it will just post the value of the radio which is selected. You can get it by `$_POST['radio_name']` .

Here it is `$_POST['add_item']` .

If you are interested to use jquery, you can do that in this way

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input:radio').click(function(event) { 
        $('input:radio').not(this).attr('checked', false);
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
}); 
</script>
```